# ES6 in Skewer-repl mode of Spacemacs

Tags: javascript, spacemacs

I'm pretty sure that I started skewer mode and run repl properly.
But it seems like it can not execute ES6 javascript.
Is it just because skewer doesn't support ES6 or there is a setting I missed?

[image]

If there is an alternative way to use ES6 in spacemacs, it would be awesome to know that. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, so I just decided to use indium. This actually makes my emacs turn into perfect IDE for JS.